# Show Apache response time for POST requests, not just GET

Tags: apache

I am using Apache's mod_logio https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_logio.html to debug some slow requests on Ubuntu.

> %^FB shows "Delay in microseconds between when the request arrived and
>   the first byte of the response headers are written."

I have turned it on in apache2.conf and include %^FB in the log format that I use.

```
LogIOTrackTTFB ON
LogFormat "%{X-Forwarded-For}i %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %^FB" myformat
```

The time is included, but only with GET requests. It is not included for POST requests nor in requests that are requested as: script src="requesturl"

Is there a way to get this info for POST and script src requests?

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that it does work with all requests. I had just forgotten to use the new logging format both for secure and non-secure requests. That was the difference.